# "Failed to open stream" trying to install AsgardCMS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to install AsgardCMS and i follow the instructions from the documentation. 1. `composer create-project asgardcms/platform your-project-name`2. `php artisan asgard:install`. But when I enter the second command I get this error

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\asgard\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\asgard\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\asgard\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\asgard\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

I supposed this is due to missing .htaccess but I am not familiar what should I write in it. I have tried with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it doesn`t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like composer doesn't require all its dependencies. You can re-run `composer install` to get those again.